# Why do I have to do minus-equals for the x-coordinate but plus-equals for the y-coordinate?

Tags: c#, unity, geometry, unityscript

I found a simple script in C# in Unity5 to make the camera follow the mouse:

```
xRotation -= Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * lookSensitivity;
yRotation += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * lookSensitivity;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (xRotation, yRotation, 0);
```

I understand why the y-axis is used for `xRotation` and visa versa. I just don't understand why if I change `xRotation -= ...` to `xRotation += ...` it inverts it and the same with `yRotation`.

Comment: Might I ask why my question is being down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the way the coordinates systems are set. In particular, what it means to increment the Y coordinate for the mouse? an on the screen?. I'm not sure which convention Unity follows, but to put an example. The mouse coordinates might be (0,0) at the top-left corner and Y would increase when moving the mouse downward. On the other hand, the screen coordinates might have a Y component that increases when going up. That's why you need to flip the sign of Y but not for X, as increasing X, both for the mouse and on screen means moving to the right.

Comment: mouse Y has a possitive value when going up and a negative when going down in unity.